# Query is repeating data

Tags: sql

I am trying to create a query that shows the summation of one query's field total as a percentage of the field total of the table the query draws from. When I try to combine the table and the query in a new query I get repeated data over and over. Please help me. The Table is REG, the query is Western and the field is POPULATION. The Western query  lists only the western states from the REG table. I want to show the summation of this queries POPULATION Field as a percentage of the REG Table's total POPULATION . Please help me

Comment: Pls show an example of input, output and problem.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a lot of detail from the question, such as which database, what the table and query definitions are. Something like this should work, but you may need to cast data to decimals if you want more precision:

```
Select
    100 * Sum(Case When w.state is not null then population end) 
        / sum(population)
From
    Reg r
        left outer join
    Western w
        On r.state = w.state
```

based on your comment, this might work:

```
Select
    100 * Sum(Case When r.division = 'E. Central' then population end) 
        / sum(population)
From
    Reg r
```

Comment: Oh Man, thank you so much. I am sorry for the lack of details. I am using access 2013. The table is named REG and the SQL for the query is:

SELECT REG.[#], REG.Territory, REG.[GDP USD$], REG.POPULATION, REG.[GDP/PERSON], REG.[EE SCORE], REG.REGION, REG.[1st LANGUAGE], REG.[2nd LANGUAGE]
FROM REG
WHERE (((REG.DIVISION)="E. Central"));


The REG is the only database which as for the definition of it, I am sorry for my lack of knowledge on this term.